# Mysql triple join error:Not unique table/alias: 'cushbu_mark_user_favorites'

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, sequence

I have 3 tables in my db

1)`cushbu_users (id,first_name,last_name)`

2)`cushbu_art  (id,user_id(FK cushbu_user),title,base_price etc...)` -for store user arts

3)`cushbu_mark_user_favorites (id,user_id(FK cushbu_user),art_id(FK cushbu_art))` -for marking favourite items

I want to fetch **the all art items of a particular user favourited**
 with count of favourites each art (stored in `cushbu_mark_usier_favorites` table )

Here is my query

```
SELECT
    cushbu_art.id AS art_id,
    cushbu_art.title,
    cushbu_art.base_price,
    cushbu_art.image_name,
    CONCAT(
        cushbu_users.first_name,
        ' ',
        cushbu_users.last_name
    ) AS artist_name,COUNT(cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id)
FROM
    cushbu_art
JOIN cushbu_mark_user_favorites ON cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id = cushbu_art.id
JOIN cushbu_users ON cushbu_users.id = cushbu_art.artist_id 
LEFT JOIN cushbu_mark_user_favorites ON cushbu_art.id=cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id
WHERE
    cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id = 68
```

But i got `Not unique table/alias: 'cushbu_mark_user_favorites'`  this `join` statement

```
LEFT JOIN cushbu_mark_user_favorites ON cushbu_art.id=cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT
    a.id AS art_id,
    a.title,
    a.base_price,
    a.image_name,
    CONCAT(
        c.first_name,
        ' ',
        c.last_name
    ) AS artist_name,COUNT(b.art_id)
FROM
    cushbu_art a
JOIN cushbu_mark_user_favorites b ON b.art_id = a.id
JOIN cushbu_users c ON c.id = a.artist_id 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.art_id
WHERE
    b.user_id = 68
```

Comment: So what is unclear …? Since you are joining the same table more than once, you need to use aliases, so that it is never ambiguous at any time which instance of it you are referring to ...

Comment: @chiragsatapara here is the explained version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373911/mysql-joinget-total-favourites-for-each-item-along-with-each-row

Comment: Sure   i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query.

```
SELECT
    cushbu_art.id AS art_id,
    cushbu_art.title,
    cushbu_art.image_name,
    CONCAT(
        cushbu_users.first_name,
        ' ',
        cushbu_users.last_name
    ) AS artist_name , b.favorites_count as total_fav
FROM
    cushbu_mark_user_favorites 
LEFT JOIN cushbu_art ON cushbu_art.id=cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id
LEFT JOIN cushbu_users ON cushbu_users.id = cushbu_art.artist_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT art_id,count(*) as favorites_count FROM cushbu_mark_user_favorites GROUP BY art_id) as b ON b.art_id=cushbu_art.id
WHERE cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id=1
GROUP BY cushbu_art.id
```

Hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: error `n aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'cushbu_db.cushbu_art.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Another error `Unknown column 'cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: No errors but i cout result are wrong  count is always 1

Comment: You can not select the content of a column that is not part of your GROUPing, that is illegal in standard SQL.