# Mysql Join:get total favourites for each item along with each row

Tags: mysql, node.js, join

Sample input for my `DB`

1)cushbu_users

```
id first_name last_name email 
   1   sh        s         sh@sh.com
   2   sb        s         sh1@sh.com
```

2)cushbu_art

```
   id user_id title   image_name 
   1    1     cool    cool.jpeg
   2    2     funny   funny.jpeg   
   3    1     blaaa   blaa.jpeg
   4    2     foo     foo.jpeg
```

3)cushbu_mark_user_favorites-Store the details of favourited item

```
 id user_id art_id
  1   1       1
  2   1       2
  3   2       1
  4   2       2 

 As you see two users Favorited  two arts so the total count 
 for favourite of each art is `two`
```

I want to get the favourited arts of each user with total favourite

My excepted output for user of id=1

```
art_id artist_name total_fav
1       sh s        2
2       sb s        2
```

Here is the query for that

```
    SELECT
        cushbu_art.id AS art_id,
        cushbu_art.title,
        cushbu_art.image_name,
        CONCAT(
            cushbu_users.first_name,
            ' ',
            cushbu_users.last_name
        ) AS artist_name , count(cushbu_mark_user_favorites.id)  as total_fav
    FROM
        cushbu_mark_user_favorites 
    LEFT JOIN cushbu_art ON cushbu_art.id=cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id
    LEFT JOIN cushbu_users ON cushbu_users.id = cushbu_art.artist_id
    WHERE cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id=1
    GROUP BY cushbu_art.id
```

But it returns

```
art_id artist_name total_fav
    1       sh s        1
    2       sb s        1
```

returns `total_fav` only `1` for each row but the excepted output `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are filtering `WHERE cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id=1` so it's not possible to get the number of favorites from other users. The idea is to join the table a second time, but without this contraints.
Speculating, untested...

```
SELECT
    cushbu_art.id AS art_id,
    cushbu_art.title,
    cushbu_art.image_name,
    CONCAT(
        cushbu_users.first_name,
        ' ',
        cushbu_users.last_name
    ) AS artist_name , b.favorites_count as total_fav
FROM
    cushbu_mark_user_favorites 
LEFT JOIN cushbu_art ON cushbu_art.id=cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id
LEFT JOIN cushbu_users ON cushbu_users.id = cushbu_art.artist_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT art_id,count(*) as favorites_count FROM cushbu_mark_user_favorites GROUP BY art_id) as b ON b.art_id=cushbu_art.id
WHERE cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id=1
GROUP BY cushbu_art.id
```

Comment: getting an sql syntax error nearer `cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id=`

Comment: returns another error In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'cushbu_db.cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't try to write all that in one go without testing... Now?

Comment: returns empty rows

Comment: Sry let me check again its the issue with user id

Answer (score -1):

Since you are doing GROUP BY cushbu_art.id, that is why is it returning 1. For your desired output, you can do a subquery , getting the count seperately.

```
`SELECT
        cushbu_art.id AS art_id,
        cushbu_art.title,
        cushbu_art.image_name,
        CONCAT(
            cushbu_users.first_name,
            ' ',
            cushbu_users.last_name
        ) AS artist_name , (select count(*) from cushbu_mark_user_favorites a where a.id=b.id )  as total_fav
    FROM
        cushbu_mark_user_favorites b
    LEFT JOIN cushbu_art ON cushbu_art.id=cushbu_mark_user_favorites.art_id
    LEFT JOIN cushbu_users ON cushbu_users.id = cushbu_art.artist_id
    WHERE cushbu_mark_user_favorites.user_id=1
    GROUP BY cushbu_art.id
`
```